# Compress and encode string dropping last two bytes

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a VB.NET app that generates an XML document that I need to post to a web app.  Before I post the XML, I need to compress the XML and base64 encode it.  Below I have a code snippet where I take an XML string, compress using gzip and then base64 encode.  To make sure what I am doing is correct, I am then decoding the base64, then gzip decompress.  After I decompress, the original XML is 2 bytes longer than my tested XML.  I am dropping the last 2 bytes somewhere.  Where did they go?

```
    Dim xml As String = ds.ToXMLString()

    ' compress and encode
    Dim ceb() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml)
    Dim cems As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
    Dim cegz As New System.IO.Compression.GZipStream(cems, IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Compress)
    cegz.Write(ceb, 0, ceb.Length)
    Dim cees As String = System.Convert.ToBase64String(cems.ToArray())

    ' i want to make sure everything is working,
    ' decode and decompress and make sure it matches
    Dim ddb() As Byte = System.Convert.FromBase64String(cees)
    Dim ddms As New System.IO.MemoryStream(ddb)
    Dim ddgz As New System.IO.Compression.GZipStream(ddms, IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Decompress)
    Dim ddms2 As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
    ddgz.CopyTo(ddms2)

    Dim xmlRestored As String = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ddms2.ToArray())

    Assert.AreEqual(xml.Substring(0, xmlRestored.Length), xmlRestored) ' <-- SUCCESS
    Assert.AreEqual(xml.Length, xmlRestored.Length) ' <-- FAILS; xml.length=147802; xmlRestored.length=147800;
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.  I wasn't closing my compression stream.  Should be like this:

```
Dim xml As String = ds.ToXMLString()

' compress and encode
Dim ceb() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml)
Dim cems As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
Dim cegz As New System.IO.Compression.GZipStream(cems, IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Compress)
cegz.Write(ceb, 0, ceb.Length)

' i was missing the closing of the gzip stream
cegz.Close()

Dim cees As String = System.Convert.ToBase64String(cems.ToArray())

' i want to make sure everything is working,
' decode and decompress and make sure it matches
Dim ddb() As Byte = System.Convert.FromBase64String(cees)
Dim ddms As New System.IO.MemoryStream(ddb)
Dim ddgz As New System.IO.Compression.GZipStream(ddms, IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Decompress)
Dim ddms2 As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
ddgz.CopyTo(ddms2)

Dim xmlRestored As String = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ddms2.ToArray())

Assert.AreEqual(xml, xmlRestored) ' <-- SUCCESS
Assert.AreEqual(xml.Length, xmlRestored.Length) ' <-- SUCCESS
```